# How to give Permission to Moodle 4.0 to view BBB recorded sessions

Tags: apache, moodle, ubuntu-20.04, error-logging, bigbluebutton

**Hi, I recently installed Moodle 4.0 on my Ubuntu server 20.04 and It came with Big Blue Button Plugin integrated offered by Blindside Networks. The BBB works perfectly fine and records. The problem I can not see the recorded sessions, I contacted Blindside Networks guys they said they see my recordings in their server and are published I should check my Moodle server to give rights.

Can You assist me where is the error or how to give rights on my Moodle server to view the recorded sessions.

Kind regards**

- BigBlueButton activity in Moodle and making sure that the "Record the session" option is checked.
- Making sure that the BigBlueButtonBN plugin is properly installed and configured in Moodle 4.0, both on the server-side and the client-side.
- Checking for apache errors in Moodle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up cron for Moodle?

BigBlueButton needs cron to update the list of recordings in Moodle

You can run cron manually from the command line to test

```
php admin/cli/cron.php
```

But you should set up cron to run automatically every minute, the instructions are here

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Cron

After recording a session, run cron a few times, you should see something like this

[image]

The presentation button is the recording