# BBB Recording is not showing in my Moodle Site

Tags: moodle, bigbluebutton

I have a problem. My problem is related bigbluebutton. When I start recording a lesson, the lesson is recorded, but it is not uploaded to the system. For example;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdjmV.png)

I'm getting this error when I look at the log page:

I, [2023-08-13T12:51:53.608989 #330293]  INFO -- : Sending request to http://www.dehaonline.com/mod/bigbluebuttonbn/bbb_broker.php?action=recording_ready&bigbluebuttonbn=16

I, [2023-08-13T12:51:53.932772 #330293]  INFO -- : Callback HTTP request failed: 400 Bad Request. Caught exception: "kid" empty, unable to lookup correct key (code 400)

Is the problem bbb_broker.php? How i can solve the problem?

I tried rebuild recording but it doesnt solve the problem. I reached my bigbluebutton server administrator and he told me  the problem was caused by moodle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is cron running?

[How to give Permission to Moodle 4.0 to view BBB recorded sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629979/how-to-give-permission-to-moodle-4-0-to-view-bbb-recorded-sessions/76630820#76630820)

Can you try running cron from the command line to see if there are any errors?

```
php admin/cli/cron.php
```