# Recordings show "No data to display" when using scalelite BBB & Moodle

Tags: ubuntu

I encountered the same problem as question.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629979/how-to-give-permission-to-moodle-4-0-to-view-bbb-recorded-sessions](https://stackoverflow.com)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbKKi.png)

I checked moodle's cron, everything works perfectly OK. But recordings still don't show presentation. If you have solved it, please share.
Many thanks.